# How do I fix my printList function in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, assembly, mips

I have to print an array in mips, but I have to work with some given code that I'm not allowed to change.
As of right now it is printing the correct amount of times, but it prints out a huge number that isn't what I am inputting for the numbers in the list. Everything in the following code is given besides what I've written under printList. Can someone help me fix this or at least steer me in the right direction? Any tips for the remaining functions would be welcome too.

```
.data 

original_list: .space 100 
sorted_list: .space 100

str0: .asciiz "Enter size of list (between 1 and 25): "
str1: .asciiz "Enter one list element: \n"
str2: .asciiz "Content of original list: "
str3: .asciiz "Enter a key to search for: "
str4: .asciiz "Content of sorted list: "
strYes: .asciiz "Key found!"
strNo: .asciiz "Key not found!"



.text 

#This is the main program.
#It first asks user to enter the size of a list.
#It then asks user to input the elements of the list, one at a time.
#It then calls printList to print out content of the list.
#It then calls inSort to perform insertion sort
#It then asks user to enter a search key and calls bSearch on the sorted list.
#It then prints out search result based on return value of bSearch
main: 
    addi $sp, $sp -8
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, str0 
    syscall 
    li $v0, 5   #read size of list from user
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0
    move $t0, $0
    la $s1, original_list
loop_in:
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, str1 
    syscall 
    sll $t1, $t0, 2
    add $t1, $t1, $s1
    li $v0, 5   #read elements from user
    syscall
    sw $v0, 0($t1)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    bne $t0, $s0, loop_in
    move $a0, $s1
    move $a1, $s0

    jal inSort  #Call inSort to perform insertion sort in original list

    sw $v0, 4($sp)
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, str2 
    syscall 
    la $a0, original_list
    move $a1, $s0
    jal printList   #Print original list
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, str4 
    syscall 
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    jal printList   #Print sorted list

    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, str3 
    syscall 
    li $v0, 5   #read search key from user
    syscall
    move $a3, $v0
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    jal bSearch #call bSearch to perform binary search

    beq $v0, $0, notFound
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, strYes 
    syscall 
    j end

notFound:
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, strNo 
    syscall 
end:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp 8
    li $v0, 10 
    syscall


#printList takes in a list and its size as arguments. 
#It prints all the elements in one line.
printList:
    move $t3, $0
    loop1:
    sll $t4, $t3, 2
    add $t4, $t4, $s1
    li $v0, 1   
    move $a0, $t4
    syscall
    sw $v0, 0($t1)
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    bne $t3, $s0, loop1


    jr $ra


#inSort takes in a list and it size as arguments. 
#It performs INSERTION sort in ascending order and returns a new sorted list
#You may use the pre-defined sorted_list to store the result
inSort:
    #Your implementation of inSort here

    jr $ra


#bSearch takes in a list, its size, and a search key as arguments.
#It performs binary search RECURSIVELY to look for the search key.
#It will return a 1 if the key is found, or a 0 otherwise.
#Note: you MUST NOT use iterative approach in this function.
bSearch:
    #Your implementation of bSearch here

    jr $ra
```

Comment: By the looks of things, the list address and list length are passed to `printList` in `$a0` and `$a1`. But your code never uses those values. Why?